# Expand Rows Based on Column

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating hierarchies and need to outline them in the format on the right-hand side.  It would be a lot easier if I could simply outline the hierarchy in one column and automatically have it expand (left -> right in the sample). 
A few considerations:

1. Within the first column, the start of a new hierarchy will always be the value 'A'
2. Hierarchies can range from 2-10 children in length

Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Where from the code must start looking for 'A'? Are all the hierarchies on column A:A? If not, based on what logic to find the next column keeping hierarchies? Do you know in which next column can they be found? Will the interior of the cell starting the hierarchy be colored in yellow and none of the other cells will have such an interior color? What logic do you suggest to be applied in order to identify the hierarchies range?

Comment: The yellow is just a highlight in this example... no need for the final result. Each hierarchy should be A:A-1 (so in this case, A-E and A-G). Ideally, this would be an Excel formula to keep it simple but am happy to work with whatever is necessary

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand what you try to say... So, all the hierarchies will start from a cell in column A:A and will end to the J:J column (maximum of 10 children)? If yes, are there empty rows between two such consecutive hierarchies?

Comment: Will all your hierarchies from the sheet have column headers as in your pictures (DIRECT, L1, L2, L3 and so on)?

Answer (score 0):

You do not answer my questions and I cannot wait, anymore...

Please test the next code, which works based on the thowe assumptions: Your hierarchies in discussion have all the time a kind of header (`Direct` in column A:A and `L1` in B:B). This, or an empty row sets the bottom part of the hierarchy.

Here's the code:

```
Sub HierarchyArrangeMultipleR()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long, lastR As Long, lastH As Long
  Dim arrI As Variant, arrTr As Variant, colN As Long, k As Long, h As Long

  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'please, use here your worksheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

  For k = 1 To lastR
    If lastH > 0 Then k = lastH + 1
    If k >= lastR Then Exit For
Start:
    If sh.Range("A" & k).Value = "Direct" And sh.Range("B" & k).Value = "L1" Then
        For i = 1 To 10
            If sh.Range("A" & k + i).Value = "Direct" Or _
                  sh.Range("A" & k + i).Value = Empty Then
                lastH = k + i - 1: Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        For h = 3 To lastH - k
            sh.Cells(k, h) = "L" & h - 1
        Next h
    Else
        k = k + 1: GoTo Start
    End If
      arrI = sh.Range("A" & k + 1 & ":A" & lastH).Value
      ReDim arrTr(1 To UBound(arrI) - 1)
      colN = 1
      For i = k To lastH - 2
        For j = 1 To UBound(arrTr) 'lastH - i + k - 2
            arrTr(j) = arrI(j, 1)
        Next j

        colN = colN + 1
        sh.Range(sh.Cells(k + 1, colN), sh.Cells(lastH + 1 - colN, colN)).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrTr)
      Next i
      Erase arrTr
  Next k
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Type the letters in column A only, start each new sequence with the word HEADER. Then run the macro and the expansions should be created.

```
Sub expand()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim cell As Range, cellHeader As Range
    Dim irow As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim iCount As Integer, iLast As Long

    ' find last row in col A
    iLast = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'scan down the sheet
    For Each cell In ws.Range("A1:A" & iLast)

        If UCase(cell) = "DIRECT" Then

            ' remember the header line
            Set cellHeader = cell
            With cellHeader
                .BorderAround xlContinuous
                .Font.Bold = True
            End With

        ElseIf Len(cell) > 0 Then

            cell.BorderAround xlContinuous

            ' start of sequence
            If cell = "A" Then
                irow = 1
                iCount = 0
            End If

            ' add header value
            With cellHeader.Offset(0, irow)
                .Value = "L" & irow
                .Font.Bold = True
                .BorderAround xlContinuous
            End With

            ' copy cell diagonally upwards
            If irow > 1 Then
                For i = 1 To irow - 1
                    cell.Offset(-i, i) = cell.Value
                    cell.Offset(-i, i).BorderAround xlContinuous
                Next
            End If

            ' check max children
            iCount = iCount + 1
            If iCount > 10 Then
                MsgBox "Children count > 10", vbCritical, "Error"
                Exit Sub
            End If
            irow = irow + 1
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "Expansion Complete", vbInformation
End Sub
```